# How to get decode format from MediaCodec?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am working with `MediaCodec`

I am using it for decode `.mp4` video

MediaCodec decode a video to `YUV` format, but I need to get `RGBA`

All is ok, but I found out that there is a few possible formats like `YUV420`, `YUV422` and so on...

So, as far as I understand to make conversion I need to know exactly which conversion to apply `YUV420_to_RGBA` or `YUV422_to_RGBA` or something else...

So, question is - how using `MediaCodec` get know about decoding format?

Feel free to ask.

**EDIT**

I found out that this way I can get `COLOR_FORMAT`

```
 AMediaFormat_getInt32(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, &format_color);
```

But, I get number 117 ...

How to know what is this number equals?

Comment: The color formats are defined in [MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html). I don't see 117 in the list. What device are you using? See e.g. [XBMC](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/xbmc/cores/VideoPlayer/DVDCodecs/Video/DVDVideoCodecAndroidMediaCodec.cpp) for an example of working with video color formats.

Comment: @fadden but in this sample he also use the same way to get `format_collor`, and then he compare with list of supported formats. But why I get `117` ... I checked in `CodecCapabilities` and there is no such format that equivalent with this number...

Comment: Could be a custom format, could be a bad MediaFormat object. Do the rest of the values in MediaFormat look valid?

Comment: @fadden no, object itself is good, all other values is correct... I would like to ask you something else here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238371/if-is-it-possible-to-get-bgr-from-mediacodec, maybe you have idea?

Comment: @fadden thank, eventually I found how to get the right value... It was just a stupid mistake....  Posted answer

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @fadden eventually I found the problem, I tried to get `AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_COLOR_FORMAT` from not right `AMediaFormat`...

It was like this **NOT RIGHT**

```
AMediaFormat *format = AMediaExtractor_getTrackFormat(ex, i);
int format_color;
AMediaFormat_getInt32(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, &format_color);
```

Here `format_color` was `117` - some not valid value...

Right way to get `AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_COLOR_FORMAT` is

```
AMediaCodec *codec = AMediaCodec_createDecoderByType(mime);
AMediaCodec_configure(codec, format, nullptr, nullptr, 0);
AMediaCodec_start(codec);
int format_color;
auto format = AMediaCodec_getOutputFormat(codec);
AMediaFormat_getInt32(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, &format_color);
```

Here `format_color` = 21 according to this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html `21 is COLOR_FormatYUV422Flexible`