# MediaCodec render on offscreen GL Texture notworking on some specific video

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

I am doing some video frame extracting work, based on the sample given by BigFlakes's [example code](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt)

It worked well for most of the videos I tested with, however, there are some video clips which I shot by my phone, cannot be correctly extracted by this method. Please refer to the screen shot. The correct frame is extracted by default MediaMetadataRetriever, and the "image of the colors" is extracted by the sample code.

**Correct Frame:**

[image]

**False Frame:**

[image]

**The testing video clip is here**
It can be played by extractor + mediacodec + surface without any problem
[Nest.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IVOxgRbAIgxpSPTIp-nfmmo7NKNV8Cpv)

It seems that the problem is from the GL Texture Rendering. Could anyone help to point out what could possibly go wrong? Why it works for most of other videos while it always fail on some of the video clips?

Comment: The color palette looks correct, though perhaps Y-inverted, so it could be a bad handle to stale data. I think your thought that it's a problem in the texture rendering (or handling) is correct. When you say "some images", is there a pattern to it, e.g. every 15th image? Is it always the same frames, or is it different frames in every playback? Is there a difference in encoding parameters, e.g. failing videos are at a higher bitrate? Have you tried playback on a device with a different graphics/media chipset? How many threads do you have, and what are you doing on each of them?

Comment: @fadden Thanks a lot for your comment. The video can be extracted to multiple different frame images(should be same different images on every execution). I tried many video clips, only 3 of the videos shot by my SAMSUNG phone could lead to this issue, I test it on Pixel1/3 nexus5x, SamsungS10 and the results are the same. The video is low bitrate, and comparing to other videos, they have more P frames I guess. I did not modify the sample code a lot, and I think it just create one thread to work, and send back the bmp obj to main thread for displaying.